# MongoDB query on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

I am storing some numbers in mongodb. For e.g.

- num1:5
- num2:10
- num1:11
- num2:15

I want to find documents where for e.g. if I pass '7' the query should check if 7 lies between num1 and num2 and must return me this document.

I tried

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("num1", new BasicDBObject("gte", 7).append("num2",new BasicDBObject("lte", 7)));
```

and

```
List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
        obj.add(new BasicDBObject("num1", new BasicDBObject("gte", 7)));
        obj.add(new BasicDBObject("num2", new BasicDBObject("lte", 7)));
        query.put("$and", obj);
```

Both are not returning me the any result. Could you please let me know correct query for my purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to add `$` to operators. And I also suggest to use QueryBuilder for this case, it is much more convenient:

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("num1").lessThanEquals(7).and("num2").greaterThanEquals(7).get();
```

I assume that `num1` is always not greater than `num2` .

Comment: any idea on how to solve the same problem with `Filters` in mongo 3.3.0 and above?